# How to use a delay function for 100ms in C?

Tags: c, windows

I would like to use a delay or sleep function in a C program under Windows64 to create a time delay of about 100ms. Which function is recommended? With the following example i always get the warning: implicit declaration of function usleep.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Processing... ");

    for(int i=0; i<50; ++i) {

        usleep(100000); // 100ms

        int position = i%4;

        switch(position) {
            case 0: printf("\b|"); break;
            case 1: printf("\b/"); break;
            case 2: printf("\b-"); break;
            case 3: printf("\b\\"); break;
        }
    }
    printf("\nDone!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So use the proper `#include` for `usleep`.

Comment: The `usleep(3)` man page tells you header file you need for the correct function definition (run `man 3 usleep`).

Comment: BTW: Be arware that the warning containing `implicit declaration` should always be considered as a serious error.

Comment: Did you try to search for the warning message? That should tell you exactly what to do.

Comment: @ScottHunter Isn't usleep posix specific? (I include `unistd` to use it). And obsolete (man page say we should use `nanosleep`)

Comment: One hundred milliseconds is only a tenth of a second. Not much time to twirl the “busy/wait” batton.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended? That is asking for an opinion.

The following give me satisfactory results (Windows specific, as requested.):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main( void ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ ) {
        putchar( "|/-\\"[ i & 3 ] );
        putchar( '\b');
        Sleep( 100 ); // 100ms // NB: Uppercase function name!
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It's even comical to comment out the second `putchar()`. (Like an acrobat!)

Comment: Many thanks! It works with Sleep() function.

Comment: We're here only to serve, with no thought of reward...